# TYPO3 Extension: I changed my extension folder name and now TYPO3 throws an error message

Tags: typo3

So today my extension_builder overwrote my entire TCAs while saving, so I did something stupid: I changed the folder name of my extension via winscp and uploaded the backupfolder of my extension I made yesterday. Now I get the error message

```
Oops, an error occurred!
TYPO3 Fatal Error: Extension key "icingaconfgen" is NOT loaded!
```

I know the error could be fixed with changing the state of the extension in the PackageStates.php to inactive, but the problem is: The extension doesn't appear in this file. Interesting enough the foldername I changed my old old extension folder to ("x") appears in the file as inactive though. What should I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you meant the extension **key**. This key is used in differnt files of an extension.
If you rename an extension folder the old key still is used in some files. TYPO3 analyses all extensions and joined (active) parts into cached files, so be careful as what is active executed and what is stored on the disk can differ (always clear all caches - there are a lot of caches!)

One part of your problem may occur of two folders with the usage of the same extension key. here especially the foder you renamed, as there the foldername and the internal extension key do not match.

TLDR:
**NEVER** rename an extension folder inside of `typo3conf/ext/`.
If you want to backup an extension move it to e.g. `typo3conf/ext.bak/`.
**Always** clear all caches after such a manipulation. (With newer versions of TYPO3 it is at least `typo3temp/Cache/Code/`, but also have a look at `typo3temp/autoload/` and the *internal* caches tables in the database.)

Answer (score 1):

If there is no non-existent extension listed in your `PackageStates.php` you should be fine after clearing TYPO3s cache.

Go to the install tool and do it under "important actions".

Or remove the contents of the `typo3temp` folder.